# How do I select soft-deleted records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do I select soft-deleted records? For performance reasons, I need to update *every* record in my table before I do a migration.

This doesn't work:

```
SearchDefault.where('deleted_at IS NOT NULL')
```

because it produces this SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "search_defaults" WHERE "search_defaults"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (deleted_at IS NOT NULL)
```

I'll be happy with a solution that either selects every record, or every soft-deleted record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you have a `default_scope` adding that condition. Try:

```
SearchDefault.unscoped.where('deleted_at IS NOT NULL')
```